# how to retrieve custom links in a wordpress submenu?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, navigation

I've created a wordpress menu with wp_nav_menu. How do I get my submenu (layout on the right of my child pages) to echo the main navigation of that page(so it shows child links of the page you are on) and include custom links?

At the moment I have this which does show all child pages of a parent page but completely ignores any custom links i add in the wp_nav_menu navigation, which i understand is because it is looking at the page hierarchy instead:

```
<body>
<!--sub menu side bar -->
        <?php 
        $PageArray = get_pages(array(
            'child_of' => get_the_ID()
        ));

        if ($theParent or $PageArray) { ?>
        <div class="page-links">
          <h2 class="page-links__title"><a href="<?php echo get_permalink($theParent); ?>"><?php echo get_the_title($theParent); ?></a></h2>
          <div class="wave_page-links"></div>
          <ul class="min-list">
            <?php
                if ($theParent) {
                    $findChildrenOf = $theParent;
                } else {
                    $findChildrenOf = get_the_ID();
                }
                wp_list_pages(array(
                    'title_li' => NULL,
                    'child_of' => $findChildrenOf,
                    'sort_column' => 'menu_order', /*change page order in page attributes*/
                ));
            ?>
          </ul>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
```

Comment: Refer to this link. So, you should find both ways to add custom link in the menu; ** https://firstsiteguide.com/wordpress-menus-tips-and-tricks/ and U**se "Use the Custom Links panel to add a custom link to your menu, such as a link to an external website. Simply type in the website URL in the URL field and the menu name in the Link Text field. Click the Add to Menu button when done. Use the same steps outlined previously to adjust the order of the menu item and click the Save Menu button at the top or bottom of the screen to save your changes.**"

Comment: Thanks for commenting though it doesn't answer my question. I'm after a way to display the child links of a parent sub page(when im on that page) to display as a side menu. I already have it picking up the child pages, but it does not show custom links i have added to the main navigation. Suspect it is because i am calling the side menu with wp_list_pages (obviously custom links are not pages) but unsure what alternate function to use?